# PHP код на странице или ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Можно ли заменить php код на странице на ajax запросы? Т.е. создать отдельный php файл к которому будет обращаться js при загрузке страницы через ajax(XMLHttpRequest obj), это позволит создать некую модульность. Можно ли так делать, как это повлияет скорость загрузки и прочее?

P.S. Весь php код, подлежащий замене, выполняется сразу же при загрузки страницы.

Comment: Если страница может быть сформирована целиком, то с точки зрения производительности, лучше целиком ее и создавать. дополнительные ajax запросы после открытия страницы будут медленее и создадут повышенную нагрузку на сервер. А вот визуальное время загрузки, это другой вопрос, если данные получаемые ajax не особо важные и в глаза сразу не бросаются, то сама страница визуально может открыться быстрее, просто часть данных появится на ней позже

Comment: Весь php код состоит в основном из обращений к бд, получение определенных данных, слышал что использование sql запросов на самой странице не очень хорошая идея, а вот почему?

Comment: Я никакой разницы не вижу когда вы сделаете обращение в БД на странице или в ajax. запросы занимают время, значит если вы их используете на странице то она грузится медленнее. если вы их перенесете в ajax, то ничего особо не изменится, страница загрузится быстро, но на ней не будет данных, которые должен подгрузить ajax, а он будет выполнять те же обращения к БД и пока они идут у вас на экране будет красоваться страница без части данных ... Количество запросов надо просто минимизировать, а где именно они выполнятся значения обычно не имеет

Comment: Следует отделять логику работы с БД от представления, иначе в какой-то момент Вы осознаете, что масштабируемость Вашего приложения нулевая. Почитайте про паттерн MVC, фреймворки и т.д., очень многого нового узнаете :)

Comment: [Наглядный пример](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/from_flat_php_to_symfony2.html#isolating-the-presentation), как это можно осуществить хоть и на английском.